# How do I call a smart contract with additional fees in web3py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3py

I am trying to call a smart contract (bridge) via web3py. The bridge function has an additional fee that can be estimated by calling another contractfunction.

When building the transaction vie web3py it seems as there is never enough gas to satisfy its demands though it can be estimated pretty well by using the protocols website.

I simply do not know what I am doing wrong here? Can sb elaborate?

Here is the call for the contract fee:

```
quoteData = contract.functions.quoteLayerZeroFee(
    dstChainId,  # destination chainId
    functionType,  # function type: see Bridge.sol for all types
    toAddress,  # destination of tokens
    "0x",  # payload, using abi.encode()
    params
).call()

messageFee = quoteData[0]

feeeth = w3.from_wei(quoteData[0], 'ether')
print('MessageFee',feeeth)
```

Output: MessageFee 0.000853629707348709

and transaction building afterwards on the corresponding router contract for eth-bridging:

```
tx = contracteth.functions.swapETH(dstChainId, walletaddress, walletaddress, w3.to_wei(0.0002, 'ether'), 0).build_transaction({
    'from': walletaddress,
    'value': messageFee + w3.to_wei(0.0002, 'ether'),
    'maxFeePerGas': w3.to_wei(100000, 'gwei'),
    'maxPriorityFeePerGas': w3.to_wei(1, 'gwei'),
    'nonce': nonce
})

signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, private_key)

tx_token = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
print(w3.to_hex(tx_token))
```

and this raises the error below no matter how high 'maxFeePerGas' is set:

```
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'gas required exceeds allowance (19)'}
```

I have played a while with setting 'gas' and 'gasPrice' instead of 'maxFeePerGas' but no matter how high I raise the gasLimit its never enough and raises the error:

```
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'intrinsic gas too low'}
```

On the protocols website it is no problem to perform a swap with these gas settings.